# Flexible navbar broken on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a flexible nav bar that has a dropdown menu on smaller screens.  I based it off of https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

The dropdown menu breaks on smaller screens.  I have icons above the word.  So instead of "Home Home" it has a house icon instead of the first home with the title under it.

```js
//  FUNCTION FOR NAV BAR  //
function myfunction() {
  var topNavX = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (topNavX.className === "topnav") {
    topNavX.className += "responsive";
  } else {
    topNavX.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
 background-color: #66FCF1;
 overflow: auto;
 display: flex;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-right: 2%;
 border-radius: 10px;
 text-align: justify;

}
.topnav:after{
 content: '';
}
/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
}
/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
 .topnav a.icon {
  float: right;
  display: block;
 }
}
/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
 .topnav.responsive .iconJS {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
 .topnav.responsive a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
 }
}
                            /*  ABOUT ON TOP NAV BAR  */
#topNavAbout {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Walter Turncoat";
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 160%;
}
                        /*  ABOUT ON TOP NAV BAR ON HOVER  */
#topNavAbout:hover {
 background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}
                             /*  A TO Z ON TOP NAV  */
#topNavAlpha {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Cinzel Decorative";
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 160%;
}
                         /*  A TO Z ON TOP NAV ON HOVER  */
#topNavAlpha:hover {
 background-color: darkviolet;
}
                      /*  FLEX AND FONT FOR CHEESY IN NAV BAR  */
#topNavCheesy {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Bad Script";
 font-weight: 900;
 line-height: 160%;
 font-size: 1.1em;
}
                     /*  TOP NAV CHEESY ON HOVER  */
#topNavCheesy:hover{
 background-color: #FF0;
}
                  /*  CLASSIC ON TOP NAV BAR  */
#topNavClassic {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Sofia";
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 line-height: 150%;
}
                  /*  CLASSIC ON TOP NAV BAR ON HOVER  */
#topNavClassic:hover {
 background-color: burlywood;
}
#topNavDonate {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Verdana";
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 170%;
}
#topNavDonate:hover {
 background-color: #009CDE;
}
                       /*  CHANGED TEXT ON MAIN NAV BAR  */  
#topNavFav {
 font-family: "Permanent Marker";
 flex: 1;
 line-height: 160%;
}
                         /*  FAVORITE HOVER ON NAV BAR  */
#topNavFav:hover {
 background-color: #00FF00;
}
                            /*  GAME ON TOP NAV  */
#topNavGame {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Monoton";
 font-weight: bold;
}
                         /*  GAME ON TOP NAV ON HOVER  */
#topNavGame:hover {
 background-color: orange; 
}
                       /*  CHANGED TEXT ON MAIN NAV BAR  */
#topNavGod {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Finger Paint";
 font-size: .86em;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 190%;
}
                    /*  GOD-AWFUL ON HOVER OVER MAIN NAV BAR  */
#topNavGod:hover {
 background-color: white;
}
                               /*  NAV BAR GROSS  */
#topNavGross {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Nosifer";
}
                       /*  GROSS ON MAIN NAV BAR ON HOVER  */
#topNavGross:hover {
 background-color: #F00;
}
                              /*  Home ICON and TEXT */
.topNavHome {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Sedgwick Ave";
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 150%;
}
                            /*  ROULETTE ON TOP NAV  */
#topNavRoul {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Marck Script";
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
                           /*  ROULETTE ON TOP NAV ON HOVER  */
#topNavRoul:hover {
 background-color: crimson;
}
                              /*  WTF ON MAIN NAV BAR  */
#topNavWTF {
 flex: 1;
 font-family: "Rock Salt";
 font-size: .75em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
                         /*  WTF ON MAIN NAV BAR ON HOVER  */
#topNavWTF:hover {
 background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
                            <!--  MAIN NAV BAR -->
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a class="topNavHome" id="current0" href="https://www.alansmitheepicks.com"><img src="icons/home.png" title="Home" alt="Home"><br>Home</a>
  <a id="topNavFav" href="favorites.html"><img src="icons/fav.png" title="Favorites" alt="Favorites"><br>Favorites</a>
  <a id="topNavCheesy" href="cheesy.html"><img src="icons/cheese.png" title="Cheesy" alt="Cheesy"><br>Cheesy</a>
  <a id="topNavGod" href="godawful.html"><img src="icons/godawful.png" title="God Awful" alt="God Awful"><br>Godawful</a>
  <a id="topNavWTF" href="wtf.html"><img src="icons/wtf.png" title="WTF" alt="WTF?!"><br>W...T...F?!</a>
  <a id="topNavGross" href="gross.html"><img src="icons/gross.png" title="Gross" alt="Gross"><br>Gross</a>
  <a id="topNavClassic" href="classic.html"><img src="icons/classic.png" title="Classic" alt="Classics"><br>Classic</a>
  <a id="topNavAlpha" href="atoz.html"><img src="icons/atoz.png" title="A to Z" alt="Search A-Z"><br>A to Z</a>
  <a id="topNavGame" href="game.html"><img src="icons/game.png" title="Game" alt="Game"><br>Game</a>
  <a id="topNavRoul" href="roulette.html"><img src="icons/roulette.png" title="Roulette" alt="Roulette"><br>Roulette</a>
  <a id="topNavDonate" href="donate.html"><img src="icons/paypal.png" title="Donate" alt="Donate"><br>Donate</a>
  <a id="topNavAbout" href="about.html"><img src="icons/clapper.png" title="About Us" alt="Who is Alan Smithee?"><br>About</a>
  <a href="#" class="icon" onclick=myFunction()>&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.. and your question is? please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "*The dropdown menu breaks*" doesn't tell us much - what exactly is happpening? Does it not display? Does it affect the content below? Does it appear incorrectly, and if so how should it appear and how is it actually appearing?

Answer (score 0):

To append an extra class

topNavX.className += " responsive";

It should have a spacing before append the new class name.